Windows Minifilter: How to capture the primary IRP_MJ_CREATE in an FLT callback
As we know, when it comes to filesystem mini-filter drivers, there is no simple correspondence between the UserMode API calls and the IRP requests passed through an FLT instance; So when the abstracted UserMode request is made, there are lots of related IRPs passed, rather than a single one (the primary request). I wonder what may be the best approach for capturing the most relatable request. Should I rely on request's attributes? Or using a dumb selective logic (Like simply handling the first IRP_MJ_CREATE and rejecting the others for some time) is the solution ?
